# Add a custom primary key column to Identity User table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity, asp-net-core-spa-services

I'm using ASP.Net Core 2.2 Identity and it generates all required tables for me where the primary key for AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles are string fields.

Here is my ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public int StaffId { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I set a custom integer field (staffId) as primary key of the AspNetUsers table and change the data type of AspNetRoles.Id from string to integer?

Comment: Please follow [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity) steps to change the primary key to int. I guess this will solve your purpose and will not require an additional field for that.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal, I've already followed those steps. That would help with changing the default Id's data type from string to int. What I'm looking for is, adding a custom field as primary key!

Comment: By custom field I'm assuming you mean custom type as a key.  Try using the `[Key]` attribute on your field or using the generic `IdentityUser` passing in your custom type? That type would have to implement `IEquatable`

Comment: Can I have User.Id and Role.Id as integer and claims as string? If yes, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your context class you can set the primary key for the property you want to be the primary key:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasKey(c => new { ApplicationUser.StaffId });
}
```

Comment: How does it choose the key value to store in db? Hashcode?

Comment: Does it avoid creating Id column?

Comment: Based on your property type  the DB column is created.

Comment: It will not create the Id column.

Comment: @Aldert, It created Id column.

Comment: Can I have User.Id and Role.Id as integer and claims as string? If yes, how to achieve this?

Comment: I do not see Role.Id or User.Id in your example? can you enhance the question so I understand the objects and their relations?

Answer (score 0):

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```